# How to write nested for loop for getdata function in oec library?

Tags: r, for-loop

For the function `getdata(origin, destination, year, classification)`
if we run `getdata("tha", "sgp", 2015, "hs07")` we will get only bilateral trade between Thailand and Singapore.

But I need all bilateral trade in ASEAN countries. Is there anyway to do that? I tried writing nested for loop myself but it didn't work.

I am very new to r programming. The code I used was:

```
origins <- c("tha", "vnm", "mys", "idn")
destinations <- c("vnm","sgp")
for (origin in origins ) {
  for (destination in destinations) {
    getdata(origins, destinations, 2015, "hs07")
  }
}
```

Comment: You want a loop or just it do be done? Nested loop can be slower than other approaches. Besides, there're some combination that throws an error due to the missing data for the year.

Comment: I just do it to be done. Is there any others way to get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

There're some issues with the input you're using:

- 1)There're some data unavailable, which throws the following error:

  > `stop("No data available. Try changing year or trade classification.")`.
  >   It occurs specially for `vnm` and it will stop the `getdata` search;
- 2) When you run `getdata` and if you want to repeat it, you have to restart the R session and I don´t know why.

So here's an approach using only the `sgp` data (which I've changed the order with `vnm` to get the code work).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(oec)

origins <- c("tha", "vnm", "mys", "idn")
destinations <- c("sgp","vnm")



res <- lapply(origins, function(x){

  lapply(destinations[1], function(y) {
  out1 <- getdata(x, y, 2015, "hs07")
  out2 <- getdata(y, x, 2015, "hs07")
  })
})
```

This will result in a list with `data.frame` and all you need to do is bind them into one using `map_df`from `purrr`.

```
restult <- map_df(res, bind_rows)
```

which gives:

```
## A tibble: 20,049 x 31
#    year origin_id destination_id origin_name destination_name id   
#   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>          <chr>       <chr>            <chr>
# 1  2015 sgp       tha            Singapore   Thailand         0102 
# 2  2015 sgp       tha            Singapore   Thailand         0102~
# 3  2015 sgp       tha            Singapore   Thailand         0106 
# 4  2015 sgp       tha            Singapore   Thailand         0106~
# 5  2015 sgp       tha            Singapore   Thailand         0106~
# 6  2015 sgp       tha            Singapore   Thailand         0106~
# 7  2015 sgp       tha            Singapore   Thailand         0106~
# 8  2015 sgp       tha            Singapore   Thailand         0202 
# 9  2015 sgp       tha            Singapore   Thailand         0202~
#10  2015 sgp       tha            Singapore   Thailand         0202~
## ... with 20,039 more rows, and 25 more variables: id_len <int>,
##   product_name <chr>, group_id <chr>, group_name <chr>,
##   export_val <dbl>, export_val_growth_pct_5 <dbl>,
##   export_val_growth_val_5 <dbl>, export_val_growth_pct <dbl>,
##   export_val_growth_val <dbl>, export_rca <dbl>, import_val <dbl>,
##   import_val_growth_pct <dbl>, import_val_growth_pct_5 <dbl>,
##   import_val_growth_val <dbl>, import_val_growth_val_5 <dbl>,
##   import_rca <dbl>, trade_exchange_val <dbl>, pci <dbl>,
##   pci_rank <dbl>, pci_rank_delta <dbl>, top_exporter_code <chr>,
##   top_importer_code <chr>, top_importer <chr>, top_exporter <chr>,
##   color <chr>
```